# Bug in java.util.regex.Pattern of JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, regex

I accidentally came up with the following program that runs forever instead of printing out a true/false result. Is that a bug? I admit that running time (because of the greediness/reluctantness/possessiveness of the matching algorithm) could be too long (rather than infinite). Anyways, I wanted to bring this case into notice.

```
String str = "[EXCEPTION] org.jfree.chart.annotations.junit.CategoryTextAnnotationTests.testEquals(org.jfree.chart.annotations.junit.CategoryTextAnnotationTests) false java.lang.NullPointerException [STACKTRACE] org.jfree.chart.annotations.AbstractAnnotation.notifyListeners(AbstractAnnotation.java:145) org.jfree.chart.annotations.AbstractAnnotation.fireAnnotationChanged(AbstractAnnotation.java:129) org.jfree.chart.annotations.CategoryTextAnnotation.setCategoryAnchor(CategoryTextAnnotation.java:157) org.jfree.chart.annotations.junit.CategoryTextAnnotationTests.testEquals(CategoryTextAnnotationTests.java:101) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176) junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141) junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122) junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142) junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125) junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129) junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252) junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247) org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86) org.pitest.junit.adapter.CustomRunnerExecutor.run(CustomRunnerExecutor.java:42) org.pitest.junit.adapter.AdaptedJUnitTestUnit.execute(AdaptedJUnitTestUnit.java:85) org.pitest.mutationtest.execute.MutationTimeoutDecorator$1.run(MutationTimeoutDecorator.java:88) java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nsdas";
System.out.println(str.matches("\\[EXCEPTION\\] (.)* \\[STACKTRACE\\]( (.)*\\((.)*\\))*"));
```

Last but not least, please note that the prefix "\nsdas" triggers this behavior.

Comment: Please note that String::matches is implemented in terms of java.util.regex.Pattern.

Comment: your regex is indeed working but you're having something called _catastrophic backtracking_ due to the large number of ways the regular expression can match a given string. your regex is just taking too long to finish; you can check this by cutting the value of `str` by half. However, the string is not the issue rather the regular expression.

Comment: @Aominè, thank you for introducing the notion of "catastrophic backtracking." I learned something from you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that a bug?

I don't think so.  I think it is just an example of exponential backtracking cause by a poorly designed regex.

The problem is this pattern.

```
  ( (.)*\\((.)*\\))*
```

and specifically the `(.)*`.  They will match any sequence of characters **including `'('` and `')'` and `' '`**.  If you change them to `[^() ]*` you should see substantially better performance.